# applying template between nodes

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt1.0. I have to apply-templates between the nodes w:instrText and w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/> and ...Please help me..

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i/>
        <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"
    > DATE  \@ "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i/>
        <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i/>
        <w:noProof/>
        <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Wednesday</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>, February 02, 2011</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more detail than this - what do you want to transform the above XML into? What do you want to insert at the location you have highlighted? Do you need to copy the document and add extra information?

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines..I want to convert this xml into html, for that i need a xslt template..

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution using `<xsl:key>` . :)

Comment: @Dimitre: As it is, it's not a good question... ;)

Comment: @Alejandro: You know, I +1 almost all non-rubish questions to encourage people to ask questions -- the quality improvements are expected as a side effect of gaining experience in asking.

Comment: @Dimitre - kind of like giving China MFN trading status, or giving Pres. Obama a Nobel Peace Prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="w:w">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kinBetween" match="w:r"
  use="concat(generate-id(preceding-sibling::w:r[w:instrText][1]),
              '+',
              generate-id(following-sibling::w:r
                                [w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'])
             )
      "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "key('kinBetween',
         concat(generate-id(w:r[w:instrText][1]),
                '+',
                generate-id(w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'][1])
                )
         )
   "/>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided input** (corrected to be a well-formed XML document):

```
<t xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487" >
        <w:rPr>
            <w:i/>
            <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> DATE  \@ "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:i/>
            <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:i/>
            <w:noProof/>
            <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Wednesday</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>, February 02, 2011</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
</t>
```

**processes (with the identity template as no specific processing has been required) exactly the nodes within the required interval and produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t xmlns:w="w:w">
   <w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
      <w:rPr>
         <w:i/>
         <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED1487">
      <w:rPr>
         <w:i/>
         <w:noProof/>
         <w:color w:val="E36C0A" w:themeColor="accent6" w:themeShade="BF"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>Wednesday</w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:noProof/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>, February 02, 2011</w:t>
   </w:r>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: The key named `kinBetween` is defined and used to identify all `w:r` elements between two `w:r` elements with the required properties for start-interval-element and end-interval-element.